# React-Native navigation not displaying?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

I've been trying to implement React-native-navigation in my app and cant seem to make it work.

My App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import Navigator from './src/components/Navigator'


class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Navigator />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

and my Navigator.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs';
import LoginScreen from '../screens/Login';
import HomeScreen from '../screens/Homescreen'
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import App from '../../App';

 export default Navigator = () => createMaterialBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    LoginScreen: {
      screen: LoginScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Login',
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => (
          <Icon size={23} name={(focused ? 'ios-home' : 'ios-home-outline')} style={{ color: tintColor }} />
        ),
      }

  },
    Home: {
      screen: HomeScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Home',
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => (
          <Icon size={23} name={(focused ? 'ios-stats' : 'ios-stats-outline')} style={{ color: tintColor }} />
        )
      }
    },
  },

  {
    shifting: false,
    backBehavior: "initialRoute",
    initialRouteName: "LoginScreen",
    activeColor: 'white',
    tabBarColor: 'blue',
    inactiveTintColor: 'black',
    barStyle: { backgroundColor: 'orange'},
    swipeEnabled: true,
  }
);
```

Right now, the app loads, and gets access to my App.js. However, it seems to not display anything from my Navigator. I know it finds it because I had pathing errors and such to fix in it.

What obvious flaw am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

There may be some confusion between two different projects here. What you're trying to implement is from [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html). [React Native Navigation](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation), a separate project from Wix, also exists.

There are a few inconsistencies in your imports that make me suspicious that an import is failing (no capital 'S' in `../screens/Homescreen`, no 'Screen' in `../screens/Login`). And you should remove the `App` import in `Navigator`.

Here's a working example based on some assumptions I've made about what you're trying to achieve. Note that for the latest version of `react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs` I needed to add the dependencies:

```
@react-navigation/core
@react-navigation/native
react-native-paper
react-native-screens
```

YMMV. I tested with a new, bare `react-native init` app. I also needed to use React Navigation's `createAppContainer`.

```js
import React from 'react'
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs'
import { createAppContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'

import LoginScreen from '../screens/LoginScreen'
import HomeScreen from '../screens/HomeScreen'

const Navigator = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Login: {
      screen: LoginScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Login',
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => (
          <Icon
            size={23}
            name={focused ? 'ios-home' : 'ios-home-outline'}
            style={{ color: tintColor }}
          />
        )
      }
    },
    Home: {
      screen: HomeScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Home',
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => (
          <Icon
            size={23}
            name={focused ? 'ios-stats' : 'ios-stats-outline'}
            style={{ color: tintColor }}
          />
        )
      }
    }
  },

  {
    shifting: false,
    backBehavior: 'initialRoute',
    initialRouteName: 'Login',
    activeColor: 'white',
    tabBarColor: 'blue',
    inactiveTintColor: 'black',
    barStyle: { backgroundColor: 'orange' },
    swipeEnabled: true
  }
)

export default createAppContainer(Navigator)
```